# Kafka Consumer with multiple threads listen all partitions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I created a Kafka consumer that will listen the partition and seek for beginOffset and complete the poll till it reach endOffset (I know what is beginOffset and endOffset for that partition). So based on my input search condition I am filtering the listened events and assigning them to a separate list.

But This process is taking longer time and I have 20 partition to listen and search with my criteria. How can do this with multiple threads to search all 20 partitons in parallel and have a final consolidated list.

```
public List<String> searchMessages(String topicName, int partitionNo, long beginOffset, long endOffset) {

        List<String> filteredMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topicName", partitionNo);
        Properties clusterOneProps = kafkaConsumerConfig.getConsumerProperties();
        KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(clusterOneProps);
   
        try {
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topicName"), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                consumer.seek(tp, beginOffset); 
            }
        }); 
        Thread.sleep(100);    
        boolean flag = true;
        System.out.println("search started......from offset is "+beginOffset);
        while(flag) {   
        ConsumerRecords<String, Object> crs = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100L));
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : crs) {
                  // search criteria
                   if(record.value().toString().contains("01111") && record.value().toString().contains("2021-11-06")) {
                       System.out.println("founddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd "+record.offset());
                       filteredMessages.add(record.value().toString());
                   }
                   if (record.offset() == endOffset) {
                       flag = false;
                       break;
                   }
            }
         }
         System.out.println("doneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
```

---

### I am calling above method for each partition and its taking long time to complete. even with one partition also its taking above a minute. so to complete all 20 paritions it may take 20 minutes. The offset range can be 5000 for each partition (endOffset - beginOffset)

```
    **final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServer1);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "OffsetGroupTwo");
    properties.put("request.timeout.ms", 60000);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 100);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);**
```

Comment: You tagged this with spring-kafka, but you don't appear to be using Spring at all. Consider using Spring's listener container and set the concurrency to 20 (one consumer/thread per partition). https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#receiving-messages

Comment: Yes @GaryRussell. With Spring listener and concurrency I can listen all 20 partitions but looking for an option how can I consolidate each thread result ? Each thread will listen a partition, once they received the data and filter the events based on my search criteria how to consolidate the results from each thread to have final one single output List

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Spring Integration's Apache Kafka support and an aggregator...

https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator